# Loading a .txt file into C and putting data into an array

Tags: c, arrays

So I need to load a `.txt` file similar to what's written below, but could possibly be thousands long, then place them into a corresponding array. I can load the file just fine, I'm just unsure how to select what line goes to what array. (I should make it clear that the order after a command isn't consistent)

```
1    
abd     
324   
1:is a command,
abd:is a name,
324:is an id
```

Any Help Would be Appreciated.

Comment: The text file is in pretty bad shape for reliable parsing. It'd be best if you could make it so as to have all three (command, name and ID) on the same line. That would also greatly simplify the parsing algorithm and error handling.

Comment: It sure would but unfortunately isn't possible.

Comment: Is it not possible, before you run your program, to make a copy of the file and post-process it using stream text processors like `awk` or `sed` (which have their Win32/Win64 equivalent) using regular expressions and whatnot for more consistent error checking?

Comment: Maybe, ill see if there is, but I'm not familiar with C enough to know.

Comment: That kind of preprocessing has nothing to do with C as it is a set of command line tools that are used to inspect/change text files on the fly for later processing with tools, e.g. that require a strict and reliable syntax. You don't need to run them from C but they'll help simplify your C code. Could you also specify which platform you're working with, e.g. Linux? Windows? MacOS? Other?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is:

- Setup 2D array
- Loop through file until the end
- When you see the first line you add into command which will be array index 0
- When you see the second line you add into name which will be array index 1
- When you see the third line you add into ID which will be array index 2
- Then you keep doing this until the end of the file